# In Rails, what's the best practice for authorizing a user's access to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise, authorization, cancan

I'm using Devise for user authentication and basic authentication. Let's say I have defined two reciprocal associations between Users and Cars.

- User `has_many :cars`
- Car `belongs_to :user`

User A has a car with id 1, User B has a car with id 2.

What's the best practice for preventing User A from accessing the resource at `/cars/2`? I could add a before_filter for :show, :edit, :update, :destroy to each controller, but that seems tedious and repetitive. Is there any way to use Devise or CanCan for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CanCan for this, read more about it here https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

after adding `load_and_authorize_resource` to the top of your controller

you can add the following line to your ability model to only allow the cars owner to manage it

> can :manage, Car, :user_id => user.id